# Pipe, redirect or stream to osmfilter from "standard in" (stdin)

Tags: openstreetmap, command-line, bash

So many tools support chaining, or piping in data from standard input. This can decrease times needed for disk writing and also better use the memory of a machine. Examples of chaining: GDAL - "[Chaining](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_virtual_file_systems.html#gdal_virtual_file_systems_chaining)", and [osmconvert](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert#Converting_Files). For example:

```
bzcat europe.osm.bz2 | osmconvert - -o=europe.o5m
```

How can I do similar operations to include `osmfilter`? Something like this:

```
cat input.osm | osmfilter > output.osm
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One potential non-answer, from the [Ubuntu man page for osmfilter](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/osmfilter.1.html)

> The input file name must be supplied as command line argument.
>
> The file
>          must  not  be  a stream.
>
> Redirections from standard input will not work
>          because the program needs random access to the file.

Comment: Interestingly the [source code of osmfilter.c](https://gitlab.com/osm-c-tools/osmctools/blob/master/src/osmfilter.c), specifically `read_open()`, contains code for reading from stdin. Possibly some old, obsolete code. I don't have a copy of osmfilter here but you could try if it works. Looks like just omitting the input filename is enough for triggering this code.